# Can't pass closure to `Hyper::service_fn`

Tags: rust, async-await, hyper

I want to write a simple microservice with hyper:

```
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server};
use hyper::{Method, StatusCode};
use std::{convert::Infallible, net::SocketAddr};

struct ApiServer {}

impl ApiServer {
    pub async fn route(&mut self, req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, Infallible> {
        let mut response = Response::new(Body::empty());
        *response.body_mut() = req.into_body();

        Ok(response)
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));
    let mut api = ApiServer {};

    let make_svc = make_service_fn(|_conn| async {
        Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(|req| async { api.route(req) }))
    });

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_svc);

    if let Err(e) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", e);
    }
}
```

I get compiler errors:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<impl std::future::Future as std::future::Future>::Output == std::result::Result<http::response::Response<_>, _>`
  --> src/master/bin/main.rs:46:38
   |
46 |     let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_svc);
   |                                      ^^^^^ expected opaque type, found enum `std::result::Result`
   |
```

How do I rewrite the code to leave `route` function be a `ApiServer`s member function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rust error message is reversed from what you might expect: `serve()` expects a `Result` but found an `opaque` type. You need to await the return value of `api.route(req)`. Fixing other compile errors, the final code is:

```rust
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server};
use std::{convert::Infallible, net::SocketAddr};

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct ApiServer {}

impl ApiServer {
    pub async fn route(&mut self, req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, Infallible> {
        let mut response = Response::new(Body::empty());
        *response.body_mut() = req.into_body();

        Ok(response)
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut api = ApiServer {};

    let make_svc = make_service_fn(move |_conn| async move {
        Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(move |req| async move { api.route(req).await }))
    });

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_svc);

    if let Err(e) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", e);
    }
}
```

See:

- [Return Type Errors](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/07_workarounds/02_return_type.html#return-type-errors)

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. But I can't comprehend though. `move |x| async move` syntax looks frightening...

Comment: @milo My personal way is add move keyword when compiler tell you to add move keyword :p

Comment: And finally I got it! We pass closure with async block to `make_service_fn` and `service_fn` (not just closure and moving context into it). And since MakeServiceFn struct must be `Copy`able and `Clone`able I must make `ApiServer` `Copy`able and `Clone`able as well. Wuh, despite I used to be a C++ developer Rust makes me cry sometimes :)